# WordPress 5.9 and CiviCRM 5.46 Donation Forms JQuery Errors

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, jquery

After updating my CiviCRM install I have noticed I am getting the following errors in my console on pages that have my donation forms.

```
jquery-ui.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: V.each is not a function
jquery.mousewheel.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fixHooks')
select2.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: e.extend is not a function
jquery.form.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: e(...).get is not a function
```

These errors continue on and it looks like just about every .js file is throwing an error. I am going back through the release notes but of course I can not confirm which version I upgraded from to 5.46. Is there anything obvious I can check for why this is not working?

Comment: I have a few questions: what payment processor are you using?   Are you using a shortcode or direct link to the donation page?   If a shortcode, is the page built with a page builder?

Comment: I'm also seeing this behaviour on Wordpress 5.9.2 CiviCRM 5.47.3 using stripe payment processor 6.7.1

Comment: Also seeing on a public profile page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a system with WordPress 5.8.4 and CiviCRM 5.47.4. and what solved it for us was one of the theme's compatibility function called [Defer jQuery And jQuery Migrate](https://divibooster.com/disable-jquery-deferral-in-divi/) which (un)changes the order in which jQuery / jQuery Migrate is registered.