Is it normal that public pages made in FormBuilder are not showing?
On the https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/, I duplicate afformQuickAddIndividual and make it Accessible on front-end of website Then when trying to see the form, I got a blank page. Is this a bug or do I miss something?

I think for the form to show publicly you need to change the Permissions on the form eg set it to

Generic (allow all users including Anonymous)

That won't happen just be cloning, and not sure from your question whether you altered it or not.
UPDATE
There is a good checklist here which makes clear that both the Form settings and the Individual entity settings need to be correct. HTH
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4462#note_172996

I just made it "Accessible on front-end of website". I still got a blank page with the generic (allow all users including anonymous). The link won't work for long, but still: https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/test/

see my update above. hth

Thanks @petednz for your link.
Here is a small screen recording with Chrome on a Mac os 10.15. I also got the blank page with Firefox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5cgxdpqiitycuyt/Enregistrement%20de%20l%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202024-11-09%20%C3%A0%2019.37.15.mov?dl=0

if i clone New Individual on dmaster then i get to see the form https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/pdtest2 but suspect i am not following the steps closely enough

It works on dpmaster, but not on wpmaster... Should I report a bug with wordpress?

suggestion has been made on Chat that this is likely to just be caching - can you clear and try again

Well, on WPMaster, when I clean the cache, I can now see the page on the front-end. It definitely is an issue on my website. I dit exactly as on WPMaster and I get a 500 internal error: https://lajoiedevivre.net/civi/test1234/ If someone has an idea where to look to resolve this...

This worked for me: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/41787/17344 (Différer jQuery et jQuery Migrate in WP Divi Theme options )
I close this topic.

I have the same issue in WP 6.6.2 but the answer @Fredatipik posted doesn't work for me as I am not using Divi but default templates/template builder. Is there any fix for this in vanilla WP? Or did I just miss something?
Edit: Clearing the cache in Civi did it for me.
Having @Fredatipik's marked as the solution is somewhat misleading for folks who don't expand the comments on @petednz first answer.

that is up to Fred. if folk +1 mine then it should sit at the top
